# Why I can't see the hotspot traffic?

Tags: android, hotspot, tethering, android-vpn-service

I want to know how it can be possible to manage the traffic of the clients connected to my android hotspot. The two mainly features I want to achieve are:

- Deny/allow the internet access to clients.
- Measure the amount of data consumed by client.

I'm using VpnService that allows me to point all my device traffic to a tun interface. I can see every IP packet passing trough the tunnel coming from my device, But after trying a lot (many days), **I assumed that is impossible to see the android hotspot's traffic.** According to my knowledge, it could be because the layer of the android hotspot is below of the VpnService and the packets are sent transparently out of the tunnel. am I right ?

The VPN interface is built as:

```
mInterface = builder.setSession("MyVpnServiceSession")
        .addAddress("10.0.0.2", 32)
        .addRoute("0.0.0.0", 0)
        .establish()
```

Please, somebody knows how can I achieve these features using (or not) VpnService or other solution ?

Thanks

PS. Answer **must work for NON-ROOTED devices**